# Lenovo B590 doesn't see external microphone

Tags: drivers, sound, lenovo, microphone

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo B590 and it doesn't see external microphone. With windows it works like a charm. With linux when I connect headphones with mic, headphones work, but mic shows as not-connected.

Tried to add to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi
options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-amic
```

And no luck.

lspci output:

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

How can I make mic working?

Answer (score 1):

Try `options snd-hda-intel model=sony-nomic`.  The pin configuration for the headset mic (/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/init_pin_configs: "0x18 0x03a11830") claims that it supports presence-detection, but it doesn't.

Comment: Finally I got my mic working after more than 5 years of having this laptop. Thanks